# recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener is not registering click

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am developing an app. This app initially downloads a package of GPS tagged images. Now, I on my home screen I show a list in recycler view. This is the list of names of the images in the package. They are listed in ascending order of the angle between mobile's y-axis and line joining mobile's origin and image's gps location. I am using `magnetometer` and `accelormeter` to find relevant angular data, and also getting GPS location from the mobile.

Now, whenever GPS location or sensor data is changed, I call `computeNearby()` which computes the order of items in the list. When I click an item, it opens another activity.

Here is my code

```html
     private void refreshRecyclerView() {
        //setting the view of the NEARBY tab
//        Log.v(LOGTAG, "going to set sorted interest points");
        recyclerViewAdapter = new NearbyPointsRecyclerViewAdapter(sortedInterestPoints);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

//        Log.v(LOGTAG, "Set sorted interest points and going to set OnItemTouchListener for recycler view");
        recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(
            new RecyclerViewOnItemClickListener(getActivity(), new RecyclerViewOnItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
                    Log.v(LOGTAG,"onItemClick registered in RecyclerViewOnItemClickListener");
                    RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder = recyclerView.findViewHolderForLayoutPosition(position);
                    //getting the title of the clicked interest point
                    TextView textView = (TextView) viewHolder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardview_text);
                    String text = textView.getText().toString();

                    Intent intent_interest_point = new Intent(getActivity(), InterestPointActivity.class);
                    //passing the title of the clicked interest point to InterestPintActivity
                    intent_interest_point.putExtra("interest_point", text);
                    Log.v(LOGTAG,"InterestPointActivity is called");
                    startActivity(intent_interest_point);
                }
            })
        );
    }



@Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        currentLatitude = location.getLatitude();
        currentLongitude = location.getLongitude();
        //Toast.makeText(_context, currentLatitude + " WORKS " + currentLongitude + "", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        computeNearby(currentLatitude, currentLongitude);
        refreshRecyclerView();

    } 

@Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

        if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER)
            mGravity = event.values;

        if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD)
            mGeomagnetic = event.values;

        if (mGravity != null && mGeomagnetic != null) {
            float R[] = new float[9];
            float I[] = new float[9];

            if (SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(R, I, mGravity, mGeomagnetic)) {

                // orientation contains azimuth, pitch and roll
                float orientation[] = new float[3];
                SensorManager.getOrientation(R, orientation);


                oldAzimuth = azimuth;
                azimuth = orientation[0];
                pitch = orientation[1];
                roll = orientation[2];                          
                computeNearby(currentLatitude, currentLongitude);
            }
        }
    }


public void computeNearby(Double currentLatitude, Double currentLongitude) {
//some sorting operations
for (int i=0; i<Math.min(TRUNCATION_LIMIT, interestPoints.size()); i++) {
            interestPoint = interestPoints.get(finalThreeAngleIndices.get(i).second);
            sortedInterestPoints.set(i, interestPoint);
        }

        refreshRecyclerView();

    }
```

I use recyclerView() method to set the screen after sorting.

So basically it goes `onLocationChanged-->computeNearby-->refershRecylerView`
and `onSensorChanged-->computeNearby-->refershRecylerView`.

But when I click any list view item, the click is not registered. When I call computeNearby from only onLocationChanged , the item click is registered and relevant activity is started. I think there is a problem with handling onSensorChanged. Please help me out.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

You have many other ways to handle Click. but i suggest you handle inside ViewHolder.

1. Store your data to ViewHolder
2. SetOnClickListener for view which contain ViewHolder

   ```
   public class CardViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

   private Context context;

   private Card data;

   public CardViewHolder(View view) {
       super(view);
       titleView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.titleView);

       view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               // Handle your click listener
           }
       });
   }

   public void setContext(Context context) {
       this.context = context;
   }

   public void setData(final Card data) {
       this.data = data;
       if(data != null) {
           titleView.setText(data.name);
       }
   }
   public Card getData() {
       return data;
   }
   }
   ```

Comment: I edited the question, please check it again. I don't think there is a direct  problem with addOnItemClickListener. The problem somewhere lies with onSensorEvent.  I am not sure though.